In PDFsharp, the Width and Height of PdfPage appear to be marked obsolete. How to fix all the warnings?
For example this line:
gfx.DrawString(
    "Bit Depth: " + lightning.BitDepth, 
    new XFont("Arial", 14), 
    XBrushes.Black, 
    new XRect(50, 330, page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.TopLeft);

Both page.Width and page.Height are obsolete.
The warning message:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning (active)    CS0618  'XUnit.implicit operator double(XUnit)' is obsolete: 'In PDFsharp 6.1 implicit conversion to double is marked obsolete, because it led to misunderstandings and unexpected behavior. Use the XUnit.Point property instead.' PdfReporter.cs  54

How to change it? If someone can show me how the line should look like, then I will apply it for all the other lines with the same warnings I have.
There is no XUnit.Point, there is XUnit.FromPoint

The warning you're seeing comes from the implicit conversion from XUnit to double, probably because of the value generated by unit conversion determined by the Type (XGraphicsUnit) property.
You get this warning because you're using the XRect(double x, double y, double width, double height) Constructor, and you're passing [PdfPage].Width and [PdfPage].Height, which represent a XUnit, that triggers the implicit operator for the conversion.
The suggested change is to use the XUnit.Point property directly instead, which returns a double value, where the Type is set to XGraphicsUnit.Point.
You just need to change page.Width and page.Height to page.Width.Point and page.Height.Point, so:
[...] new XRect(50, 330, page.Width.Point, page.Height.Point) [...]

Marking as Obsolete the implicit operator, informs that previous implementations may get an unexpected result now, but it currently returns the same value as the XUnit.Point property.

A Unit object can be set to e.g. "1in". In that case, the implicit conversion will return 72 and not 1 - and this can be confusing. Therefore, the implicit conversion is now marked obsolete. The result has not changed, but the implicit conversion could be removed in future releases.

@IlikedtheoldStackOverflow That was my understanding. I've added a note about the [Obsolete] warning, since one may decide to temporarily suppress it, to clear the clutter, then fix it later, knowing that the value returned is for now correct -- Of course, code marked as obsolete can be removed at any point in the future
